Determine maildir file accessed by PHP's IMAP extension
I'm nearing the completion of refining my mail import function. There are a small number of email messages that throw off PHP's IMAP extension functions.
My server uses maildir (contrasting Dovecot) so each message is a dedicated file.
When an email message fails to parse the only thing I can manage to get is the message number or "unique" id. However I can't get any other identifying information with the PHP IMAP extension functions that I'm familiar with (e.g. imap_errors()).
How can I identify the maildir file in the Linux file system on my server that IMAP has associated with either the message number or "unique" id?
If I'm able to isolate the file I can confirm which message is causing problems for the parser and further investigate what else I can do to keep the mail import script running without problems. In example non-compliant formatting for headers (typically spammers). Though I need to confirm what is what just-in-case a malformed message is mission critical for a client or myself.

PHP's IMAP extension does not access maildir files directly. It is an implementation of IMAP client, it's designed to access mail using IMAP protocol specifically, so it connects to the IMAP server, which in turn accesses its storage (whatever it is) to retrieve messages. IMAP protocol here plays the role of an abstraction layer, so it's no wonder imap_error doesn't show you anything about files — there is no such thing as "files" in IMAP, it's abstracted out. It only can show errors about protocol or server.
In your case server storage maybe happens to be maildir, but, depending on the server and its features, it could be anything. It can be not a file, but a database record, for instance. MS Exchange can talk IMAP protocol, but it doesn't use maildir for its storage, but its own storage structures. Cyrus IMAP doesn't use maildir, it's files, but also uses its own on-disk directory structure. No matter how it's stored in the server, however, over IMAP it is identified using the message UID, which is the only way to identify the message over IMAP. Only the IMAP server knows how these UIDs relate to the storage files, or records, or whatever it has.
So, if you are really using IMAP (which you are, if you are using IMAP extension — or, it can be POP3 and/or NNTP, which are very close things for the purpose of this discussion), in PHP you don't have access and should not have access to the information about the storage and its problems, and can't solve these problems, even if it so happens that PHP and IMAP server run on the same system. If some messages are inaccessible and display IMAP errors, you should consult your IMAP server logs and resolve the problems with the server software and it's storage.
If errors are, however, message parse errors, it might be there is no problem on the level of the IMAP protocol. In that case, your server may successfully retrieve and send the message to the PHP's client, but the parser chokes. That would mean the MIME parser you use in your PHP application is buggy or otherwise fragile; you should fix that instead. But it wouldn't be an error detectable using IMAP extension.
Also, please notice that PHP's built-in IMAP extension is deprecated and not bundled since PHP 8.4, so you should stop using it at all. Take a look on PHP-IMAP module for a replacement.

Thank you for the effort...I was hoping for more of a "use this IMAP function to look at a different part of the message" or "this IMAP function will tell you the total size of the raw email so if it's 0 there is nothing to parse". Then I could simply iterate through the directory looking at file sizes or download the files and look for a string on a malformed message through a program like Advanced Find and Replace.

In principle, IMAP supports partial message access and server-side search, so it's necessary for the IMAP server to also parse them. But, in case server parser errors, it should drop a note into its log file and probably show you a protocol error, and the full message body (which would be a malformed MIME struchure) should be still available anyway.
